# CLI Contact Import is not importing address details

Tags: api, import, error, cli

I have a local test environment on a mac where the site is installed.

I'm trying to do a CLI import via the mac terminal and unfortunately, address details are not being imported.

Command Used:
php [absolute path]/sites/all/modules/civicrm/bin/csv/import.php -e Contact --file [absolute path]/csv/test.csv

Column headers:
"contact_type","email","first_name","middle_name","last_name","street_address","city","state_province","country","gender","custom_1"

Sample CSV:
"Individual","person.email@local.dev","FirstName","MiddleName","LastName","Street Address Details","City Name","State Name","Country Name","Female","custom_1 value"

As you can see above, there's even a custom value and it get's imported, but address details are not.

Please help.

Mac: El cap, Drupal: 7, CiviCRM: 4.7

Answer (score 4):

The CLI Contact import is meant to work on a per-entity basis, since it uses the API.  So Contact is a separate entity from Address.  The Contact entity API has a couple of hacks to accept certain parameters from other APIs - e.g. primary email address - but generally speaking, what you're doing is unsupported.

If you'd like to do what you're doing via command-line, you have a couple of options:

- Pull the contact ID into your CSV, and do a second import using the Address entity.
- Write a small PHP script that handles this using the API Chaining rules.
- If you're super-ambitious, you could write support for API Chaining into the existing CLI import, or submit a paid issue queue item to the core team to do so.

If this is a one-time import and you're not a coder, the first choice is the easiest.  Do your initial contact import first.  I use a tool called Pentaho Kettle to automate the process of substituting contact IDs into my address etc. imports - but it's got a steep learning curve if this is a one-off job.  Instead, export contact ID and external identifier from Civi, open it in a spreadsheet program, and use a VLOOKUP formula to generate your address import.